# Can we make low strength neodymium magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is its possible to make neodymium magnet with strength of 4000 gauss ?

Comment: I presume you could use some non-magnetic filler…

Comment: There are different grades of neodymium magnet material that can be used to make magnets. I have found this page, [link](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/specs.asp), to be really useful for information about those different grades.

Comment: Is it possible to go below all those grades and get 4000 guass

Answer (score 0):

You can use magnetic field having a direction that is opposite to the direction of the magnetic field of the magnet. This will flip the magnetic field of some of the domains of the magnet. It is also possible to use alternating decreasing magnetic field. However, it may be difficult to calculate the required magnetic field.

Comment: Is it possible to make new magnetic alloy for achieving 4000 gauss

Comment: @KunjSolanki : I don't understand that. Isn't it easier just to make a smaller magnet?

Comment: No for my application need to use ferrite core so neodymium magnets will saturate it and ceramic magnet lose its strength in long run , so my question is by   making new alloy can we make 4000 gauss magnet

Comment: @KunjSolanki : I still don't understand why a smaller neodymium magnet would not suit you. Maybe you should tell us more about your application.

Comment: Is it possible to use all magnetic field of neodymium magnet in ferrite core . And my application need high frequency so